# How can I get wrapped Ether on Polygon Mumbai?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, polygon, opensea

how can I get Wrapped ETH (wETH) on Polygon Mumbai (Testnet)?

I'd like to have some WETH in PolygonTestnet for further testings on OpenSea (Testnet-stage). How to archive this?

The official Polygon Bridge offers only some Goerli related support but nothing to wrap some ETH.

Comment: Were you able to bridge WETH from Goerli to Mumbai? It should be possible here: https://wallet-dev.polygon.technology/bridge (but at the moment it doesn't seem to be working)